# Show menu item description with line breaks

Tags: menus, themes, description, line-breaks

I have a problem with my theme...

I use Agama, and i've checkmarked "description" in the menu settings, but it won't display it on the frontend, since the theme doesn't allow it.

But then I found this function:

```
function prefix_nav_description( $item_output, $item, $depth, $args ) {
if ( !empty( $item->description ) ) {
    $item_output = str_replace( $args->link_after . '</a>', '<span class="menu-item-description">' . $item->description . '</span>' . $args->link_after . '</a>', $item_output );
}
return $item_output;
}
add_filter( 'walker_nav_menu_start_el', 'prefix_nav_description', 10, 4 );
```

That helped me get the description to be shown.
But i can't make line-breaks in my description. Everytime I just make a line-break or inserts 
 and save the changes, it removes the changes again.

So can anyone help me with a function that both makes the description be showned and also makes it possible for me to add 
 in the description.

Thanks :D

Comment: It's really strange. I'm testing this and the description gets saved to the database with a line break, but when it's output into the textarea again for editing the line break is removed, so it will get saved without a linebreak the next time its saved. As far as I can tell this textarea is escaped with `esc_html()` but in my testing I can't get `esc_html()` to remove line breaks, so I don't know why they're removed here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, it took me a little while to debug this behaviour, but... Everything is clear for me right now... I'm not sure if this is fully intentional...

### Why is it so?

So... The line breaks are stored in DB correctly. Then in `wp_setup_nav_menu_item` the description field is filled based on `post_content` column of given menu item post.

On line 845 (https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.9/src/wp-includes/nav-menu.php#L845) it is shortened and filtered:

```
if ( ! isset( $menu_item->description ) ) {
    /**
     * Filters a navigation menu item's description.
     *
     * @since 3.0.0
     *
     * @param string $description The menu item description.
    */
    $menu_item->description = apply_filters( 'nav_menu_description', wp_trim_words( $menu_item->post_content, 200 ) );
}
```

And the `wp_trim_words` function trims text to a certain number of words, but it doesn't preserve line breaks - so any line break is replaced with space.

### So what can we do about it?

There are no filters in `wp_trim_words` that will allow us to modify its behaviour. There is also no filters that will allow us to skip `wp_trim_words` call, but...

You can replace the `\n` with some placeholder and then use `nav_menu_description` filter to replace it back. There even is no need that users put this placeholder himself - we can replace them with a placeholder with `save_post` filter:

```
function replace_nl_placeholder_nav_menu_description( $description ) {
    return str_replace('%NL% ', "\n", $description);
}
add_filter('nav_menu_description', 'replace_nl_placeholder_nav_menu_description');

function replace_nl_with_placeholder_nav_menu_description( $post_id ) {
    if ( 'nav_menu_item' !== get_post_type($post_id) ) return;

    remove_action( 'save_post', 'replace_nl_with_placeholder_nav_menu_description' );

    wp_update_post( array(
        'ID' => $post_id,
        'post_content' => str_replace("\n", '%NL% ', get_post_field('post_content', $post_id, 'raw'))
    ) );

    add_action( 'save_post', 'replace_nl_with_placeholder_nav_menu_description' );
}
add_action( 'save_post', 'replace_nl_with_placeholder_nav_menu_description' );
```

And that's all. You only have to remember to properly display such line breaks in your theme (`nl2br` and so on).

Comment: Oh man, what an obnoxious filter `nav_menu_description` is! It doesn't even pass through the menu item object.

Comment: @JacobPeattie I guess no one ever used it ;)

Comment: Nice digging. Since I am already using ACF on the website I ran into this problem with, I decided to use an ACF field assigned to menu items with a description box of my own. Sharing here in case anyone is in a similar boat.